# AngularJS trigger ng-change on input type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I need help for `angularjs`.

I want to trigger `ng-change` on input type number input field.

```
 <input 
   ng-required="true"
   ng-change = "onChangePrePay()"
   type="number"
   ng-model="entry.team.prepaidEntriesNum"
  />
```

but on-change is triggered only when input field loses focus. Any idea how to override this behavior. It's totally unexpected.

Comment: your code doesn't have `ng-change` in it

Comment: typo still not working

Comment: There must be something else wrong because this is generally not a problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/ckx1346m/

Comment: tnx for helping you are right, i will let you know tomorrow after inspection the code

Answer (score 3):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlMain',function($scope){
  $scope.test = 23; 
   $scope.onChangePrePay = function(){
       alert('CHANGE');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlMain">
        <input 
         ng-required="true"
         ng-OnChange = "onChangePrePay()" */change here in your code ng-OnChange instead of ng-change
         type="number"
         ng-model="test"
        />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

to check trigger change on the input use **ng-change** not **ng-onchange**

Answer (score 0):

replace "ng-onchange" with "ng-change"

Comment: yeah thats the whole point of my question, it's well known issue but some noob down voted my question

Comment: try this : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-change
if you change the input type to number, the change method works

Comment: tnx for helping you are right, i will let you know tomorrow after inspection the code